react-sigma client-rendering TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0')
I am developing an application for next js + neo4j + sigma js.
Only 2 pages:

A page with an input and a "Search" button.
The page /search?query=123, which displays a graph of relationships (the result of a query to neo4j).

The graph is built using the sigma js library (more precisely, react-sigma https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-sigma ).
Communication with Neo4j is working correctly.
The problem is that when you click on the "Search" button, the following error pops up (even 2):
error № 1
error № 2
Further, when the page is updated, the graph is displayed correctly.
Logically, I realized that the problem occurs during the rendering of the page (namely the graph) on the client side. I don't know how to fix it.
Home page:
    import Form from "next/form";
        
        export default function Home() {
          return (
            <Form action="/search">
              <input name="query" />
              <button type="submit">Submit</button>
            </Form>
          );
        }

Page "/search":
import getSearchResults from "@/app/search/search";
    import ResultGraph from "@/app/search/resultGraph";
    
    export default async function Page({
      searchParams,
    }: {
      searchParams: { [key: string]: string | string[] | undefined };
    }) {
      const { query } = await searchParams;
      const results = await getSearchResults(query);
    
      return (
        <div>
          <ResultGraph resultSearch={results} />
        </div>
      );
    }

the component that displays the graph:
(the test graph is shown here as an example)
"use client";
    
    import { Sigma, RandomizeNodePositions, RelativeSize } from "react-sigma";
    
    export default function ResultGraph(resultSearch) {
      let myGraph = {
        nodes: [
          { id: "n1", label: "Alice" },
          { id: "n2", label: "Rabbit" },
        ],
        edges: [{ id: "e1", source: "n1", target: "n2", label: "SEES" }],
      };
    
      return (
        <div>
          <h1>This is the future Count!</h1>
          <Sigma graph={myGraph} settings={{ drawEdges: true, clone: false }}>
            <RelativeSize initialSize={15} />
            <RandomizeNodePositions />
          </Sigma>
        </div>
      );
    }

Additionally, I'm not sure if these things are related, but even after updating and supposedly displaying correctly, error 500 into the console:
error № 3
Please help me. Thanks!
I think that something wrong with client rendering
